# Javascript. Order of execution of asynchronous functions

Tags: javascript, async-await

Just now I had a discussion with my team-lead, and I have some doubts about his words, looking for professionals' help.

For example, we have three async functions

```
const fetchViewers = async () => { 
   const viewers = await fetch(...);
   this.setState({ viewers });
};
const fetchPolls = async () => {
   const polls = await fetch(...);
   this.setState({ polls });
};
const fetchRegistrants = async () => {
   const registrants = await fetch(...);
   this.setState({ registrants })
};
```

And we are invoking them in such order

```
const init = () => {
   fetchViewers();
   fetchPolls();
   fetchRegistrants();
}
```

And let's say that fetching viewers takes far more time than two others,
my question, is there any reason to put `fetchViewers` last?
Since we are not waiting for them to be resolved in the `init` function, I'm pretty sure that it doesn't matter because it only affects the order it will be put in the stack, and the calls will be made by the DOM.
If it does matter, please explain more detailed why.

Comment: Yes, it won't matter.. But I do hope your not using the functions like that `init` is showing, you have lost all error checking and the ability to know when init is finished.  At least place in a `Promise.all`..

Comment: Since you are not expecting anything from all those requests, the order does not matter.
If you are expecting some data, it matters. You can do it this way to have them in some order: `const viewers = await fetchViewers()` for every function with different const and ofc make the init async function.

Comment: The order does matter. Or at least, it's not that simple.

Comment: IMHO, in `async` functions, you should *not* rely on the order - it should be concurrent. Implementation will have some order though; for example, the first function will mostly likely be the first to *queue* up. (This is my limited understanding.)

Comment: I added more details in the question

Comment: There is also the issue of the number of concurrent http connections you can have.

Comment: *"I have some doubts about his words"* but the question doesn't contain what he has said, nor what you're questioning about it.

Comment: @3limin4t0r he wanted me to put fetchViewers last, and said `Javascript has a single-threaded event loop.  It’s never truly independent if you have multiple async operations

You still have to take order of execution into account when you code` and I just didn't want to  because I think that order doesn't matter

Comment: @GlooMpiQueWeb Re-arranging the lines would change the order in which the requests are made, but not the order in which the responses are handled. The response order is depended upon the speed of the request.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli  Good point!, although with http2/spdy I would assume this is less of an issue due to it been able to multiplex, unless of course your connecting to multiple servers.

Answer (score 2):

Asynchronous functions still run synchronously *till the first `await`*. Therefore if you do some long running preparations before the actual asynchronous action, the order does matter. Also if the asynchronous task is accessing a shared ressource (e.g. they are locking the same database, for example) the order *could* influence how well the tasks can run in parallel (this is outside JS' scope though). In the case given however I can't really see synchronous code / a shared ressource (except for bandwith, but that should hardly matter), so it *should not matter*. To give an absolute answer, shuffle the calls (6 combinations, so that's not that much work) and *measure it*.

Comment: Still wont matter though, because all those fetch initial init is also going to be synchronous, there is no event tick happening between any of them for any async actions to trigger.  So all before first `await` code is going to get run first.

Comment: Yes, but fetching could start while the synchronous code still runs. Yes, usually thats nanoseconds, but it *could* matter.

Comment: if I would call all three of them with await key, then yes, they would be dependent, but in this case, we just call them synchronously, and DOM API will just return the very first resolved and put it in the call stack.

Comment: @glooMpiQue I rather meant something like `for(let i = 0; i < 10000; i++)` before the fetch, then it would make a difference.

Comment: @JonasWilms, yeah, I got it now. You right about synchronous calls. But in my case though, since all three of them async, I think it doesn't matter, as you said it just nanoseconds for them to be invoked.

Comment: Even then it doesn't seem to matter, the fetch doesn't start until all synchronous code is complete.  Well that's what seems to happen in Chrome anyway,.. If I call an `async` function, then do a long waiting blocking op, the fetch doesn't start until all blocking code is complete.  Unless Chromes debugger tools are also blocked,..

Comment: @JonasWilms  Did a bit more digging with this, tried some experiments with Firefox too.   But I think the debuggers don't report whats actually happening correctly, on both browsers.  I assume its maybe the debuggers are tied into the main JS thread.  So even though an `async` fetch has been requested, the debugger just doesn't show this info until all sync JS is complete.  So technically the order could have an effect, but like you say practically it's unlikely too,  as you should be trying to avoid blocking the main thread anyway.